# PHP MVC type issue

Tags: php, function, model-view-controller, types

I have a problem with the type of a variable in a function. And I really don't understand where. I want to make an admin interface/form which allows to modify the content of a database.
Here is the form :

```
<h1 class="mb-4 mt-4 text-center">Modifier <em> <?= $params['post']->title ?></em></h1>

<div class="container mt-4">
    <form method="POST" action="/myapp/admin/posts/edit/<? $params['post']->id ?>">
        <div class="mb-4 mt-4">
            <label for="title" class="form-label">Titre de l'article</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="title" id="title" value="<?= $params['post']->title ?? '' ?>">
        </div>
        <div class="mb-3 mt-4">
            <label for="content" class="form-label">Contenu de l'article</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" name="content" id="content" rows="8"><?= $params['post']->content ?? '' ?></textarea>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Enregistrer les modifications</button>
    </form>
</div>
```

[This is the fatal error I have :](https://i.stack.imgur.com/35jrf.jpg)

And the url :

```
http://localhost/myapp/admin/posts/edit/%3C?%20$params[%27post%27]-%3Eid%20?%3E
```

I have a function `update()` with 2 arguments; it returns an *int* and an *array*.

This function is define in my `Model.php`

```
namespace App\Models;

use PDO;
use Database\DBConnection;

abstract class Model {

    protected $db;
    protected $table;

    public function __construct(DBConnection $db)
    {
        $this->db = $db;
    }

    public function update(int $id, array $data)
    {
        $sqlRequestPart = "";
        $i = 1;

        foreach ($data as $key => $value) {
            $comma = $i == count($data) ? "" : ', ';
            $sqlRequestPart .= "{$key} = :{$key}{$comma}";
            $i++;
        }

        $data['id'] = $id;

        return $this->query("UPDATE {$this->table} SET {$sqlRequestPart} WHERE id = :id", $data);
    }

    public function query(string $sql, array $param = null, bool $single = null)
    {
        $method = is_null($param) ? 'query' : 'prepare';

        if (
            strpos($sql, 'DELETE') === 0
            || strpos($sql, 'UPDATE') === 0
            || strpos($sql, 'INSERT') === 0) {

            $stmt = $this->db->getPDO()->$method($sql);
            $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, get_class($this), [$this->db]);
            return $stmt->execute($param);
        }

        $fetch = is_null($single) ? 'fetchAll' : 'fetch';

        $stmt = $this->db->getPDO()->$method($sql);
        $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_CLASS, get_class($this), [$this->db]);

        if ($method === 'query') {
            return $stmt->$fetch();
        } else {
            $stmt->execute($param);
            return $stmt->$fetch();
        }
    }
}
```

Then this function is called in my `PostController.php` and `Post.php` where it should return a integer but apparently it returns a string.

```
namespace App\Controllers\Admin;

use App\Controllers\Controller;
use App\Models\Post;
use App\Models\Tag;

class PostController extends Controller {

    public function edit(int $id)
    {
        $post = (new Post($this->getDB()))->findById($id);
        $tags = (new Tag($this->getDB()))->all();

        return $this->view('admin.post.form', compact('post', 'tags'));
    }

    public function update(int $id)
    {
        $post = new Post($this->getDB());

        $tags = array_pop($_POST);

        $result = $post->update($id, $_POST);

        if ($result) {
            return header('Location: /myapp/admin/posts');
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my `Route.php`

namespace Router;

```
use Database\DBConnection;

class Route {

    public $path;
    public $action;
    public $matches;

    public function __construct($path, $action)
    {
        $this->path = trim($path, '/');
        $this->action = $action;
    }

    public function matches(string $url)
    {
        $path = preg_replace('#:([\w]+)#', '([^/]+)', $this->path);
        $pathToMatch = "#^$path$#";

        if (preg_match($pathToMatch, $url, $matches)) {
            $this->matches = $matches;
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    public function execute()
    {
        $params = explode('@', $this->action);
        $controller = new $params[0](new DBConnection(DB_HOST, DB_NAME, DB_USER, DB_PWD)); // Connexion variables
        $method = $params[1];

        return isset($this->matches[1]) ? $controller->$method($this->matches[1]) : $controller->$method();
    }
}
```

And my `Router.php`

namespace Router;

```
use App\Exceptions\NotFoundException;

class Router {

    public $url;
    public $routes = [];

    public function __construct($url)
    {
        $this->url = trim($url, '/');
    }

    public function get(string $path, string $action)
    {
        $this->routes['GET'][] = new Route($path, $action);
    }

    public function post(string $path, string $action)
    {
        $this->routes['POST'][] = new Route($path, $action);
    }

    public function run()
    {
        foreach ($this->routes[$_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD']] as $route) {
            if ($route->matches($this->url)) {
                return $route->execute();
            }
        }

        throw new NotFoundException("La page demandée est introuvable.");
    }
}
```

Here is my `Post.php`

```
namespace App\Models;

use DateTime; // because using php method DateTime()

class Post extends Model {

    protected $table = 'posts';

    // some code....

    public function update(int $id, array $data, ?array $relations = null)
    {
        parent::update($id, $data);

        $stmt = $this->db->getPDO()->prepare("DELETE FROM post_tag WHERE post_id = ?");
        $result = $stmt->execute([$id]);

        foreach ($relations as $tagId) {
            $stmt = $this->db->getPDO()->prepare("INSERT post_tag (post_id, tag_id) VALUES (?, ?)");
            $stmt->execute([$id, $tagId]);
        }

        if ($result) {
            return true;
        }
    }
}
```

I pretty sure that all my routes are correct and the structure of my folders and files also.
Does somebody understand why it doesn't work ?
I think that the problem could come from my Model.php but not sure.
Thanks for any help!

Comment: This may sound odd, but you have provided _too much detail_ here: rather than expecting someone to follow the flow through all these different PHP files, try to reduce the problem down to a [mcve], or at least focus in on the specific piece of code that is producing an error. You should also include the error message as _text_, not an image - I actually completely overlooked your link at first. Click [edit] under the question and think about how you can _help others to help you_.

Comment: I'm gonna guess the arguments for `update()` are passed in through the url as route/query parameters (it looks like just `edit` is being called?). It doesn't look like these parameters are cast from a string to the specified type hints before being passed.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the error. It was in the Post.php but into a function that I didn't put in my question!

Here is the function :

```
public function getTags()
    {
        return $this->query("
            SELECT t.* FROM tags t
            INNER JOIN post_tag pt ON pt.tag_id = t.id
            WHERE pt.post_id = ?
        ", [$this->id]); // I had to add the []
    }
```